# I can't open Cassandra because of insufficient disk space to write

Tags: java, cassandra, cqlsh

I set up a new Cassandra and use `./cassandra` to open it, but it fails. In the system.log, it shows the following error:

```
ERROR 13:30:31 Exception encountered during startup java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Insufficient disk space to write 542 bytes
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.runWithCompactionsDisabled(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2888) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.truncateBlocking(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2849) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.discardCompactionsInProgress(SystemKeyspace.java:404) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:230) [apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:533) [apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:642) [apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Insufficient disk space to write 542 bytes
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFuture(FBUtilities.java:394) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.forceBlockingFlush(SystemKeyspace.java:593) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.saveTruncationRecord(SystemKeyspace.java:432) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore$13.run(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2843) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.runWithCompactionsDisabled(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2884) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]           ... 5 common frames omitted Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Insufficient disk space to write 542 bytes
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299) ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286) ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116) ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.waitOnFuture(FBUtilities.java:390) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]           ... 10 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Insufficient disk space to write 542 bytes
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Directories.getWriteableLocation(Directories.java:349) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.flush(Memtable.java:324) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore$Flush.run(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1187) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.10.jar:2.2.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
```

**the output of command "df -h":**

```
root@srv-machine-learning01:/var/lib/cassandra# df -h

Filesystem                                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/xvda1                                        61G   60G     0 100% /

udev                                              10M     0   10M   0% /dev

tmpfs                                            2.4G  8.3M  2.4G   1% /run

tmpfs                                            5.9G     0  5.9G   0% 

/dev/shm

tmpfs                                            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% 

/run/lock

tmpfs                                            5.9G     0  5.9G   0% 

/sys/fs/cgroup

bak02.sovanta.com:/volume1/bak_machine_learning   70T   19T   52T  27%
```

Comment: Which OS do you use? How much free space is on its drives? Are permissions for your data directories set correctly?

Comment: linux 3.16.0-4-amd64, the space for store Cassandra is big enough. What do you mean by permissions? because I used the binary version of Cassandra, so I think the data will be stored in the cassandra/data directory by default, I didn't set the var/lib/data directory.

Comment: whats output of `df` and whats your `data_file_directories` set to in cassandra.yaml

Comment: `data_file_directories` are commented in cassandra.yaml, I didn't set any directories for data, it's in default.

Comment: Can you uncomment the data_file_directories in Cassandra.yaml and set it explicitly to a directory where you know there is space available.

Comment: I have tried to change that directory to var/lib/cassandra/data, but it doesn't work, still with the same error. I also tried to clean up var folder to get more space, but it doesn't work, either.

Comment: @Oak Can you post the output of command "df -h"

Comment: @Oak apart from posting `df -h` can you post `ls -lah /var/lib/cassandra` - it might be that you installed cassandra via the binary packages (which in my case add a user cassandra to my system) but you have started cassandra as a normal user. This might lead to a situatuion where your files are owned by the cassandra system user and you cant read them as your login user (or vice versa). Cassandra should be started via init.d or systemctl if you use prepackaged binaries.

Comment: @dilsingi I have put the output in the question, could you check that? it seems the /dev/xvda1 is full, does it influence?

Comment: @Mandraenke I'm the root user of the system(VM), and I didn't use any other user to install Cassandra. Could you say it more in detail.

Comment: @Oak `dev/xvda1 61G 60G 0 100% /` your root filesystem is indeed full.

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly this reason. I have solved it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your root file system is full.

> /dev/xvda1 61G 60G 0 100% /

Since Cassandra stores data by default in /var/lib/cassandra and you haven't set up a different file system to use for this path it will use your root file system. I can think of several solutions for this issue.

- Free up space on root partition
- Increase disk space for your root file system
- Add a new disk to your system and create a new filesystem which mounts to /var/lib/cassandra

Answer (score 0):

go to mchine and delete unused schema of cassandra manually.